# analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [analytic functions defined on $A\cup D$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261440/analytic-functions-defined-on-a-cup-d)

Let $f$, $g$ be  analytic function defined on $A\cup D$ where
$A = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \frac{1}{2}<|z|<1\}$ and
$D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-2|<1\}$
Which of the following statements are true?

1. If  $f(z) g(z) =0$ for all $z \in A\cup D$, then either $f(z)=0$ for all $z \in A$ or     $g(z) =0$ for all $z \in A$.
2. If  $f(z) g(z) =0$ for all $z \in D$, then either $f(z)=0$ for all $z \in D$ or                     $g(z) =0$ for all $z \in D$.
3. If  $f(z) g(z) =0$ for all $z \in A$, then either $f(z)=0$ for all $z \in A$ or                     $g(z) =0$ for all $z \in A$.
4. If  $f(z) g(z) =0$ for all $z \in A\cup D$, then either $f(z)=0$ for all $z \in A\cup D$ or     $g(z) =0$ for all $z \in A\cup D$.

I am stuck on this problem. Can anyone help me please?