# multiple choice question on holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [analytic functions defined on $A\cup D$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261440/analytic-functions-defined-on-a-cup-d)

Let $f$ and $g$ be holomorphic functions defined on $A\cup D$ , where $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1/2<|z|<1\}$  and   $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z-2|<1\}$. Which of the following are true?

1. If $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z\in A\cup D$, then either $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in A$ or $g(z)=0$ for all $z\in A$.
2. If $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z\in D$, then either $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in D$ or $g(z)=0$ for all $z\in D$.
3. If $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z\in A $, then either $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in A$ or $g(z)=0$ for all $z\in A$.
4. If $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z\in A\cup D$, then either $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in  A∪D $ or $g(z)=0$ for all $z\in  A\cup D$.

How should I solve this problem?